# Uncountable Nouns vs. Plural Nouns

Tags: plural-forms, uncountable-nouns

> 1. Meals are a time for **human connection**.
> 2. Meals are a time for **human connections**.

What’s the difference between these two sentences? To me both seem to have the same meaning, and I am unable to figure out the difference between the two. I think both sentences are implying all human connections in general, then what’s the difference?

Comment: I would say that 'human connection' is the _concept_ of relationships between people, while 'human connections' are individual examples of such relationships. Which you use in your sentence depends on which aspect you want to stress.

Comment: Oh ok. So using both is correct. Am I right?

Comment: As I said, you can use either depending on your meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Connection' is not in itself an uncountable noun - you can make *a* connection, or many *connections*.

'Human connection' however is a singular concept. The difference between your examples is that one is talking about all human connections as if they are one concept while the other is considering all the individual human connections that you may make.